# Rails helper doesn't render all content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have some code which I use on many of my pages, and it's starting to get kind of laborious to go back and update everything when changes are made.

Trying to DRY up my code I thought it would be a good idea to convert the commonly used code into a helper method.  After working on this for a while, Im still having trouble getting my helper to completely render all of the html generated, and I cant figure out what Im doing wrong.

here is my helper:

```
module TablesHelper
  def table(collection, *args)
    content_tag :ul, class: "table help" do
      #first off we need a header row
      content_tag :li, class: "header" do
        args.collect do |option|
          content_tag :span, option.to_s.titleize
        end.join(' ').html_safe
      end

      collection.collect do |object|
        content_tag :li do
          args.collect do |param|
            content_tag :span, object.send(param)
          end.join(' ').html_safe
        end
      end.join(' ').html_safe
    end
  end

  def link_table(collection, *args)
    content_tag :ul, class: "table help" do
      #first off we need a header row
      content_tag :li, class: "header" do
        args.collect do |arg|
          content_tag :span, arg.to_s.titleize
        end.join(' ').html_safe
      end

      collection.collect do |object|
        content_tag :li do
          args.collect do |arg|
            #the first item on this row needs to be a link
            if arg.equal? args.first
              link_to object.send(arg), object
            else
              content_tag :span, object.send(arg)
            end
          end.join(' ').html_safe
        end
      end.join(' ').html_safe
    end
  end

  def button_table(collection, *args)
    content_tag :ul, class: "table help" do
      #first off we need a header row
      concat content_tag :li, class: "header" do
        args.collect do |option|
          concat content_tag :span, option.to_s.titleize
        end.join(' ').html_safe
      end

      collection.collect do |object|
        concat content_tag :li do
          args.collect do |param|
            concat content_tag :span, object.send(param)
          end.join(' ').html_safe
          #lets throw on the small buttons
          concat content_tag :div, class: "options" do
            concat link_to content_tag(:i, nil, :class => "fa fa-eye"), object, class: "small primary button"
            concat link_to content_tag(:i, nil, :class => "fa fa-pencil"), [:edit, object], class: "small primary button"
          end
        end
      end.join(' ').html_safe
    end
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you using those helpers with `<%= your_helper %>` (if using ERB) or `= your_helper` (if using HAML)?

Comment: It seems that your `li` with html class `header` are not being rendered. I am preparing an answer.

Comment: You would probably be better served building this out as reusable partials, YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An issue that I can see is that your helpers does not "concatenate" all of the generated content:

```
  def link_table(collection, *args)
    content_tag :ul, class: "table help" do
      content_tag :li, class: "header" do
        args.collect do |arg|
          # ...
        end.join(' ').html_safe
      end
      # RIGHT HERE, the above is not "concatenated" to the content below
      collection.collect do |object|
        content_tag :li do
          args.collect do |arg|
            # ...
          end.join(' ').html_safe
        end
      end.join(' ').html_safe
    end
  end
```

Usually, for helpers of this type (generating HTML), I do the following pattern:

```
def link_table(collection, *args)
  content = ''.html_safe

  content += content_tag(:li, class: 'header') do
    # ...
  end

  content += collection.collect do |object|
    content_tag :li do
      # ...
    end
  end.join(' ')

  content_tag(:ul, class: 'table help') do
    content
  end
end
```

---

Also, I would suggest you to DRY your `li` content tag with class `header` as they are the same for your 3 helpers. Something like:

```
def li_header(collection)
  content_tag :li, class: "header" do
    collection.collect do |item|
      content_tag :span, item.to_s.titleize
    end.join(' ').html_safe
  end
end
```

and use it like this:

```
def link_table(collection, *args)
  content = ''.html_safe

  content += li_header(collection)

  # ...

  content_tag(:ul, class: 'table help') do
    content
  end
end
```